# Is it possible to derive an Ed25519-public-key from an Ed25519-signature?

Tags: signature, ed25519, anonymity

If you have an Ed25519-signature and the signed message, can you derive the corresponding public-key or is the signature anonymous (except if you already know the public-key of course)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EdDSA), an EdDSA signature is a pair $(R, s)$ of a point $R \in E(k)$ and scalar $s \in \mathbb Z$ satisfying the verification equation $$[2^c s] B = [2^c] R + [2^c H(R, A, M)] A,$$ where $E/k$ is the underlying curve over a field $k$, $B \in E(k)$ is the standard $k$-rational base point of large prime order and cofactor $2^c$, and $A \in E(k)$ is the public key.

It is tempting to say that if you had $h = H(R, A, M)$, then you could simply compute an inverse $k$ of $h$ modulo $\ell$ and compute $A = [k] ([s] B - R)$, and hope that complications with the the covfefe $2^c$ won't eat your lunch.  But, by design, the only way to compute $h$ is in fact to know $A$ *a priori* to feed it into $H$.  And unless you break the preimage resistance of $H(R, A, M)$, which is SHA-512 in the case of Ed25519, you won't get very far doing this.

However, that only answers the question you asked literally: **Can I *derive* $A$ from an Ed25519 signature?**  You also mentioned anonymity, which is a slightly different kettle of fish.  The question for anonymity should be the [*key privacy* property](https://iacr.org/archive/asiacrypt2001/22480568.pdf): **Given two signatures $(R, s)$ and $(R', s')$, can I tell with nonnegligible probability whether they were made by the same key pair or not?**

In the case of most RSA-based signature schemes, the answer is yes (to both questions), thanks to a [problem of counting German tanks](https://blog.cryptographyengineering.com/2014/10/29/attack-of-week-unpicking-plaid/) well-known in the anglophone empirical inference literature—that is, most RSA-based signature schemes do not provide key-privacy.  What about Ed25519?

The answer may be a little trickier, because we don't demand *recovery* of the public key as the standard approach to breaking RSA-based key privacy works.  The literature does not seem to be rife with references about key privacy for signature schemes, but there is a [simpler sufficient criterion](https://eprint.iacr.org/2005/005) for key privacy of encryption schemes which could likely be adapted to signature schemes.

I leave it as an exercise for the reader to adapt this into a sufficient criterion for key privacy of signature schemes, demonstrate that Ed25519 satisfies the criterion, and publish it all to fame and glory in the cryptology literature.

Comment: The references in this post are not very good.  There are better references, and a clearer breakdown of the related notions of key privacy for _encryption_, anonymity for signature, and key indistinguishability for an exotic kind of signature, in this answer: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/67918