# Schnorr Pubkey Recovery

Tags: public-key, elliptic-curves, signature, schnorr-signature

As per [How does recovering the public key from an ECDSA signature work?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/18105), it's possible to recover public keys from ECDSA signatures.

Is this possible for EC-Schnorr signatures as well?

I'm looking specifically at https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0340.mediawiki as a reference on EC-Schnorr, but it seems to have nothing on pubkey recovery.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Fix a group $E(k)$ on an elliptic curve over a field $k$.  Suppose $P \in E(k)$ is a public key.  If a signature on a message $m$ under $P$ is the encoding of a pair $(R, s)$ of a point $R \in E(k)$ and an integer $s$ satisfying (various criteria and) the equation $$[s]G = R + [H(R \mathbin\| m)]P,$$ where $G$ is the standard base point, then you can recover $$P' = [H(R \mathbin\| m)^{-1}]([s]G - R),$$ where $H(R \mathbin\| m)^{-1}$ is the inverse in the scalar ring of $E(k)$, if there is an inverse, which is guaranteed if $E(k)$ has prime order like secp256k1.  In groups of composite order like edwards25519 or FourQ, $P'$ may not be equal to $P$ but it may serve as equivalent to $P$ for the purposes of signature verification.

**However, while that equation is discussed as an option in the BIP-Schnorr document, that's not the option they chose.**  Rather, they chose a design where a signature is the encoding of a pair $(r, s)$ of a *coordinate* $r \in k$ and a scalar $s$ satisfying (various criteria and) the equation $$r = x([s]G - [H(r \mathbin\| P \mathbin\| m)]P),$$ [somewhat like Ed25519](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/53230/49826), about which see for a related discussion of key *privacy* as even further from key *recovery*.  This leaves you with the snag that to compute $H(r \mathbin\| P \mathbin\| m)$ you must know $P$ already, or know some black magic to break the hash $H$.

**So no, the signature scheme in the documented you cited does not enable recovery of the public key from signatures.**